# matching array string values in nested for loop in PHP doesn't recognize condition

Tags: php

I am trying to strip out string values from `array $error_message_key` that match string values from `array $err_strings`. And then assign the strings that are left to `$postback`. The particular code that does the filtering in the function below is `if($error_message_key[$e] != $err_strings[$g])` but it doesn't seem to work. I still get all the string values from `array $error_message_key`.

```
$err_strings = explode('+', $catch_value);

for($e = 0; $e < count($error_message_key); ++$e)
  {
   for($g = 0; $g < count($err_strings)-1; ++$g)
   {
    if($error_message_key[$e] != $err_strings[$g])
    { 
     $postback .= '&'.$error_message_key[$e].'='.$_POST[$error_message_key[$e]]; 
    }
   }
  }
```

**UPDATE**: Here are the arrays:

```
$error_message_key = array('email','firstName','lastName','pwd','username','phone','street','city', 'country', 'postal','province');

$err_strings = array('lastName','pwd','username');
```

Array  `$err_strings` actually comes from `explode`'d string `$catch_value` which is in a form of `"lastName+pwd+firstName+"`.

**UPDATE:**

The output should be in a form of:

```
$postback = 'lastName=value&firstName=value&phone=value&....'
```

**UPDATE:**
This is actually a script that responds if a user has wrong inputs in the form. The supposed to be stripped out string are names of the  fields which would have the border color changed. The remaining string values are also names of the  fields with correct inputs which would then be refilled with the same inputs... Please feel free to suggest another way of doing this if you think it's inappropriate...

Comment: Please show some example data.

Comment: have you got some values from the variables, what are there arrays like. and please add a required output example.

Comment: so your trying to error check a form php side or you pre checking it js side ?

Comment: @RobertPitt: PHP side because I think it's safe.

Comment: Your examples are not making a whole lot of sense. `lastName` is present in `$err_string` and in `$postback`. But `firstName` is in `$err_string` but not in `$postback`. Huh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) or [array_intersect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)?

I was unable to determine if you want the strings the arrays have in common, or the ones they do not have in common, so use whichever one is appropriate.

(**Disclaimer**: untested code)

```
$entries = array_diff($error_message_key, $err_strings);
foreach($entries as $entry)
{
  $postback .= '&' . $entry . '=' . $_POST[$entry];
}
```

You may want to wrap the values with [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) if you are using this as a url.

Comment: exactly, array_diff will work. (and not array_intersect) and atlast we need to do: $postback = substr($postback, 1);

Answer (score 0):

Of course you get all of the strings. Indeed, don't you find that you get a ridiculous number of them in your output string, with many of them doubled/tripled/etc?

For each value in `$error_message_key`, you check every value of `$err_strings` for being not equal to the current value. That means that for (from the start) 'email', your code goes: "checking email against lastName... they're not equal, so add it. Now checking email against pwd... they're not equal, so add it. Now..." etc.

For an example, try running this slight alteration of your given code, which just adds `echo` to it:

```
<?php

$postback = "";

$error_message_key = array('email','firstName','lastName','pwd','username','phone','street','city', 'country', 'postal','province');

$err_strings = array('lastName','pwd','username');

for($e = 0; $e < count($error_message_key); ++$e)
  {
   for($g = 0; $g < count($err_strings); ++$g)
   {
    echo "Comparing ".$error_message_key[$e]." against ".$err_strings[$g]."<br />";
    if($error_message_key[$e] != $err_strings[$g])
    { 
     $postback .= '&'.$error_message_key[$e];// Scrapped because no $_POST. .'='.$_POST[$error_message_key[$e]]; 
    }
   }
  }

?>
```

I think you'll find the output informative as to your problem.

Comment: It's almost 3am here, must be the effect of being sleepy. Or maybe I am just too dumb to understand my code. :-)